# My PHP code is working but "printf or echo" statement is not! How to fix it?

Tags: php

I want to create tables dynamically using a variable and I successfully did it with my code, problem is when the code is executed it works and the table is created but the `echo` statement is not working and no errors are being shown upon running the code!

I've tried both `printf` and `echo` I even used `mysqli_query($mysqli, $query);` before and after `echo` statement with no luck!

Here is my code:

```
<?php
$db_user = 'root';
$db_pass = '';
$db_name = 'dbase';
$db_host = 'localhost';

$mysqli = new mysqli($db_host, $db_user, $db_pass, $db_name);

if ($mysqli->connect_errno) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", $mysqli->connect_error);
    exit();
}

$cbot = "bot_2";
$query = "CREATE TABLE `dbase`.`{$cbot}` (

        id bigint(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, 
        responses varchar(1000) NOT NULL, 
        PRIMARY KEY (id) )";


if ($mysqli->query($cbot) === TRUE) {
    echo "The bot_2 table has been successfully created.\n";
}

mysqli_query($mysqli, $query);

?>
```

I want `echo` statement to work for showing messages when script is successfully executed. Please help me fix this, I am a beginner in php.

Comment: What is this `$mysqli->query($cbot)`?

Comment: Read your code once more. It doesn't make any sense.

Comment: You're trying to execute `$cbot` which does not appear to be a query.

Comment: $cbot is a variable I created for getting input from a html field.

Comment: I replaced $cbot with $query still not working!

Comment: I mean, you're quite literally trying to execute the value of `$cbot` which is 'bot_2' and that's not valid SQL and your echo will never happen. As for replacing it with `$query` not working, the mysqli library has [functions](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php) to help you find out why they're failing.

Comment: Okay thanks guys it just worked, $query is working now.

Comment: Also note that `$mysqli->query($cbot)` does NOT return `true`. It returns a `mysqli_result` object if the query was successful or `false` if there was an error. So it's more correct to check if the result `!== false`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are passing the wrong variable to mysql query.

You are passing `$cbot` to the query which contains string `bot_2` in it rather than query:

```
$mysqli->query($cbot)
```

whereas it should be:

```
$mysqli->query($query)
```

Just replace your variable and your issue would be resolved.

Comment: Thanks I already did it a little while ago from others help in above comments, this was exactly the problem and I solved it following this solution.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$db_user = 'root';
$db_pass = '';
$db_name = 'dbase';
$db_host = 'localhost';

$mysqli = new mysqli($db_host, $db_user, $db_pass, $db_name);

if ($mysqli->connect_errno) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", $mysqli->connect_error);
    exit();
}

$cbot = "bot_2";
$query = "CREATE TABLE `dbase`.`{$cbot}` (
    id bigint(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, 
    responses varchar(1000) NOT NULL, 
    PRIMARY KEY (id) )";

if ($mysqli->query($query)) {
    echo "The bot_2 table has been successfully created.\n";
}

$mysqli->close();
?>
```

$mysqli->query($cbot) can´t work, $cbot is not a mysql statement.

Comment: Thanks, this exactly was the issue I solved it a little while ago from others help in the above comments.